# Counting observations per bucket for a given range in a prometheus Histogram

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

We're recording the duration of completed operations within our system. Every time something succeeds, we `observe` the duration using a Prometheus histogram.

- I set up the buckets using an exponential distribution: 1000, 5000, 25000, 125000, 625000.
- Each observation includes around 6 labels e.g: `operationType`, `organizationId`

**I want to count the number of observations per bucket for a specific operation type within a given range**. I tried the following queries (using a Grafana Bar Gauge with Heatmap format):

```
sum(operation_x_bucket{operationType="TypeA"}) by (le)
```

I tried using the `increase` function, but I'm clearly missing the point here (I also tried with a fixed range vector).

```
sum(increase(operation_x_bucket{operationType="TypeA"}[$__range])) by (le)
```

The result in both case doesn't make sense. **The values are way below the real number of successful operations**.

I validated that operations are properly observed, so my guess is that I'm completely misunderstanding Prometheus `_bucket` usage.

**What's the proper way to count many observation per bucket do we have for given label value?**